Opening Odoo webpages (Main page or clients page) with Android WebView (Compose)
I'm trying to open odoo website, using Android WebView. but I always get an empty page.
no errors or warnings, other pages opens with no problem. but it seems that there are specific settings in WebView for Odoo page.
I created the same application for an iOS and it opened with no issue.
I made this code

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AndroidView(
                factory = { context ->
                    WebView(context).apply {
                        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                        settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
                        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                        settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                        settings.useWideViewPort = true
                        settings.allowContentAccess = true
                        settings.allowFileAccess = true
                        settings.databaseEnabled = true
                        settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
                        settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                        settings.layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING
                        isScrollbarFadingEnabled = true
                    }
                },
                update = {
                    it.loadUrl("https://www.odoo.com/")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

what are the right settings?

It was simple. but tricky.
I had to load the data for the WebView to load Odoo website.
update = {
                    val s = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }</style></head><body><div style='height: 100%; background-color: white;'></div></body></html>"
                    it.loadData(s, "text/html", "UTF-8")
                    it.loadUrl("https://www.odoo.com/")
                }

here is the complete code. I may not need all of that, but someone might find this useful.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AndroidView(
                factory = { context ->
                    WebView(context).apply {
                        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
                        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                        settings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
                        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                        settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                        settings.useWideViewPort = true
                        settings.allowContentAccess = true
                        settings.allowFileAccess = true
                        settings.databaseEnabled = true
                        settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
                        settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                        settings.layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING
                        settings.offscreenPreRaster = true
                        settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
                        isScrollbarFadingEnabled = true
                    }
                },
                update = {
                    val s = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }</style></head><body><div style='height: 100%; background-color: white;'></div></body></html>"
                    it.loadData(s, "text/html", "UTF-8")
                    it.loadUrl("https://www.odoo.com/")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}


